# Upgrade Database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I've upgrade my database from SQL Server 2008 to 2008 R2 (v10.50.1600.1) on a remote server. Version of my local SQL Server is 10.50.1600.1.

When attempting to restore database from remote server to my system, I get this erro. How can I solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: The error message is because you are trying to restore higher version `10.50.1600` on lower version `10.00.1600` this is not allowed.

Comment: My sql  version is :10.50.1600.1 but I can't restore ....

Comment: (You need to read the error message and/or output of `SELECT @@VERSION;` or even the version number in Object Explorer a little more carefully.)

Comment: As the error message **clearly states** - your local DB version is **10.00.1600** (SQL Server **2008** - no R2)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the error message is quite clear. You have backed up a database from a SQL Server 2008R2 instance and tried to restore it on a SQL Server 2008 instance.

It is not possible to restore databases to a previous version of SQL Server. This has to do with internal database structure differences between the versions. The only way to get your data from a SQL Server 2008R2 instance onto a SQL Server 2008 instance would be to export the data and import it. You could achieve this through SSIS, bcp, Replication or Linked Servers.